# UIImage Extension Not Working Properly

Tags: swift, uiimage, extension-methods

So I am trying to set custom icons for tabBarItems in my project (because the default options are quite limited).

Apparently the icons are not automatically adjusted to be 30 x 30 as they need to be so I've been trying to do it manually using a UIImage extension. I have only used extensions once or twice, and all that I am really trying to do is convert [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780020/how-to-clip-larger-images-to-fit-into-tabbar-icons-in-tabbarcontroller-built-pro) into Swift 3. My attempt for the extension is below:

```
extension UIImage {

    func scaledToSize(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        images?[0].draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }

}
```

If it is not clear, this extension is supposed to be used like this to achieve my purpose:

```
self.tabBarItem.image = tabBarItemImage?.scaledToSize(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
```

I understand that this isn't the most elegant solution as-is, but I thought it would work and it isn't. I have tried using it with a simple imageView, but it doesn't work with that either so I don't think it is an issue with using this technique with the tabBarItems specifically.

If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong or guide me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Honest, stupid question - you have the correct contentMode set, right? If so, then the only thing that caught my eye is **images?[0].draw". Not sure if you should do that in a "single" UIImage extension.

Comment: @dfd What contentMode are you referring to? Also, can you elaborate with your second comment? I am only applying the change to one photo at a time, and so I think it should be safe to just use the first image in the array.

Comment: UIImage.contentMode == various things to make an image property "fit" the way you desire. It's pretty much the basic thing you do with a UIImageView. (I expect you have that correct, just making sure.) My second comment was referring to how you code an **extension**. If you are coding for a UIImage extension, it's almost like subclassing - you can't refer to **image[0]", as the image property of a UIImageView is singular. (I might expect that in a UITabBarView or something.)

Comment: I haven't changed the image content mode, would I need to? Also, I think I understand what you're saying about the extension part, but the issue is, in the UIImage extension it's has the property "images" but no "image". That's why I had to use the first index notation to make it singular so I could alter it. I am also a little unsure about the UIImageView part because I am simply altering the tabBarItem's image property, so I shouldn't need a UIImageView. Sorry if I'm completely misunderstanding your message, and thanks for the insight so far!

Answer (score 0):

try below extension,

```
extension UIImageView {
    func scaledToSize(size: CGSize){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        self.image!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let imageed = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.image = imageed
    }
}
```